# Is it possible to submit to multiple Data Extension in a single Smart Capture Form Submit?

Tags: dataextensions, smart-capture

In my customer registration form, I have an address field that may have dynamic number of addresses. It's not possible to create a lot of address fields in single Data Extension. So I create another Data Extension to store the addresses. This DE is apart from customer DE. Is it possible to submit the form that can submit data to BOTH customer DE and address DE with a single Smart Capture Form Submit? If not, can I have a workaround on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **No, BUT there's a workaround**.

On cloud page, create a landing page with a HTML form. Then create a "code reference with "Page setup" choose **JSON**. Below is the code reference.

1. HTML code reference(note jQuery part, you don't need to declare jQuery again as cloud page has jQuery 1.8 built in)

   ```
   <form id="cloud_page_form" onsubmit="return false;">
         <input name="field1" value="111" type="hidden">
         <input name="field2" value="222" type="hidden">
         <button type="submit">Submit</button> 
   </form>
   <script>
         $("form#cloud_page_form").submit(function(){
             $.ajax({
                 type: "post",
                 url:  "https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/<JSON_PAGGID>",
                 data: {
                     data: $(this).serialize()
                 },
                 success: function(result) {
                     //Insert your code
                 },
                 error: function(req, status, error) {
                     //Insert your code
                 }
             });
         });
   </script>
   ```
2. JSON code reference, the AMPScript and SSJS plays an important part to send data to different DE tables)

   ```
   %%[
       set @data = RequestParameter("data")
   ]%%
   <script runat=server>
       Platform.Load("Core","1");
       var form_data = Variable.GetValue("@data");
       var form_params = deparam(form_data);
       //Declare Data Extension
       var DE1 = DataExtension.Init("DE1");
       var DE2 = DataExtension.Init("DE2");
       //Request field values
       var field1 = form_params.field1;
       var field2 = form_params.field2 ;
       //Insert DE1
       var de1_result = DE1.Rows.Add({"field1": field1});
       if (de1_result != 1)
           success = false;
       //Insert DE2
       var de2_result = DE2.Rows.Add({"field2": field2});
       if (dc2_result != 1)
           success = false;
       Variable.SetValue("success", success);
       /* deparam function */
       function deparam(querystring) {
           // remove any preceding url and split
           querystring = querystring.substring(querystring.indexOf('?')+1).split('&');
           var params = {
           }
           , pair, d = decodeURIComponent;
           // march and parse
           for (var i = querystring.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
             pair = querystring[i].split('=');
             params[d(pair[0])] = d(pair[1] || '');
           }
           return params;
         }
    </script>
    {
        "success": "%%=v(@success)=%%",
    }
   ```

Note: You can use AMPScript completely. I used SSJS just because I have better understandings on JS.